# How to generate a non-abstract non-default interface method using JvmTypesBuilder

Tags: xtext, xtend

I want to generate an interface with non-default methods. For this purpose I'm using the JvmTypesBuilder.

The code

```
meth.toMethod(meth.name, meth.returnType)[]
```

generates for example

```
public default int meth();
```

Trying it with

```
meth.toMethod(meth.name, meth.returnType)[
   it.^default = false
]
```

doesn't change anything.

Setting it abstract works

```
meth.toMethod(meth.name, meth.returnType)[
  it.abstract = true
]
```

but then I get a method like

```
public abstract int meth();
```

what I don't want either.

Is there any way using JvmTypesBuilder and generate a method without default or abstract keywords?

```
public int meth();
```

I'm using Eclipse 4.5.1 for DSL Developer

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you put the method into an interface and not into a class. E.g. please set the interface flag on the `JvmGenericType` to `true`. That should do the trick.

Comment: I'm using the toInterface method. So the generated code is an interface.

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect to be generated? A method can either have an implementation (`default`) or not (`abstract`). In fact, without any modifiers, an interface method is implicitly `abstract`.

```
interface MyInterface
{
    public abstract void foo();
}
```

compiles to exactly the same bytecode as

```
interface MyInterface
{
    public void foo();
}
```

Comment: I know that, but you second code is shorter and better to read. It's only a question fo readability and appearance. I expected another behavior of JvmTypesBuilder.

Comment: In that case, it is just a matter of prettyprinting.